# How does deep packet inspection (DPI) extract metadata from packets?

Tags: ip, network, packet-analysis, traffic

DPI software extracts metadata (as an additional function apart from classifying applications / protocols)

But how does it do this? For classification, I get that you can use pattern matching or port-based matching or heuristic analysis. But for metadata extraction, **do they use these same methods?** Or do they just read the metadata from the contents and headers of packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single, rigid definition for *deep packet inspection*. It's usually understood as doing all those things: extracting transport-layer and application-layer data and analyzing it using various methods, including pattern matching, heuristics, scanning content for data-loss, malware protection, unwanted content, and so on.

Generally, DPI is known to use all information it can get at: headers, content, even breaking encryption (*SSL inspection*). Some products may even logically add metadata (from a central database) to a packet (e.g. geo location, provider, source ASN, ...) for analysis.

The capabilities of the many products vary widely, however. How those products exactly work is often a trade secret.

Comment: Thanks. I think the last line is especially correct, given that the definition of network traffic metadata itself varies by product.

Comment: Indeed - I've expanded the answer a bit on the metadata aspect.